# EOF within quoted string

Tags: r, twitter

I have a file with about 350,000 rows.
I am using

```
S.longtermtest="COKE32500.csv"
x=read.csv(S.longtermtest, row.names=NULL)
```

to read it to x.

The data is not properly specified/formatted. Below is an example where in the record with id="1020608401", there are extra quotation marks and so read.csv does not handle it the way I need. Is there a way to read in this kind of data and whenever there appear to be more than 7 fields, to just skip that record?

The 7 field names are

```
"Tweet ID","Date","Username","Text","Location","Followings","Followers"
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
"Tweet ID","Date","Username","Text","Location","Followings","Followers"
"1020580305","09/26/2012 17:01:00","LoudpackMariee","RT @marvelousbby: @LaLaaKors no you just say too much on twitter","Niggas wit coke","0","0"
"1020591756","09/26/2012 17:22:46","Sofia_Torrez","I must give up Coke. @AnahiMarcial http://t.co/O9QyXGjg","San Diego, California","0","0"
"1020594942","09/26/2012 17:24:22","PaterGH13","Con mi paisana y amiga @MireiaCarrillo  de GH 12 tomando una coke en los madriles) un gustazo verte!! Muuuuak http://t.co/V2QFqi08","Barcelona, España","0","0"
"1020595525","09/26/2012 17:24:40","WP2_DotCom","RT @UNADining: Stop by the GUC today and enter the drawing for a chance to win a coke bean bag http://t.co/URCtK1p9","Florence, Alabama","0","0"
"1020600160","09/26/2012 17:42:30","RadicalWizard_","I always block accounts like this, but this has got to be the best spam bot bio I've ever encountered. Str8 2 the point http://t.co/ICOD3zuI","Sniffing lines of coke","0","0"
"1020600792","09/26/2012 17:42:49","LexDLutor","coke boyz _ instru (prod by Lex Lut'Or) by @LexDLutor via #soundcloud http://t.co/5WW5i1uT","Bruxelles Belgique","0","0"
"1020602605","09/26/2012 17:43:45","LoudpackMariee","","RT @PardonMyLips: Forreal. RT @intoxicatedBia: You hip RT “@LoudpackMariee: This bitch tells her entire life story on twitter. ENiggas wit coke","0","0"
"1020608358","09/26/2012 17:46:40","SimplySophie","RT @BreezysLullaby: i asked for a coke not strawberry milkshake @mcdonalds!!!! http://t.co/DwC8l6iZ","Liverpool","0","0"
"1020608401","09/26/2012 17:46:41","danielzol4nski","RT @heymarkey: "@wezhopwood: A Cinema was robbed last night of £754, thieves took a bag of malteasers, a pick n mix and a large coke." h ...","Krim+Azealia's block list (UK)","0","0"
"1020644783","09/26/2012 19:00:54","klierlyshirley","Cheery coke? LOL http://t.co/bGMg2cAV","the hundred acre woods.","0","0"
"1020660546","09/26/2012 19:24:50","midsummerfrenzy","Cherry Coke is the best. http://t.co/7xzlvkOe","Tulsa, OK, USA","0","0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Th issue is that some tweets are "tweet quotes" and whatever generated the CSV did not handle them correctly. This code:

- reads in the file as a series of lines
- splits the lines when it sees `,"`; admittedly, this *could* error on some tweets, but it worked for this sample
- takes each split column and removes the surrounding quotes (i.e. de-quotes them)
- puts it all back into a data.frame (well, data.table, but almost the same)

So, it handles the tweet quotes without having to drop them.

```
tmp <- readLines("~/Desktop/tweet.csv", skip=1)

dat <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(strsplit(tmp[2:length(tmp)], '",'), function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(y) {
    gsub('(^"|"$)', "", y)
  })
}))

data.table::setnames(dat, colnames(dat), unlist(strsplit(tmp[1], ",")))

dplyr::glimpse(dat)

## Variables:
## $ "Tweet ID"   (chr) "1020580305", "1020591756", "1020594942", "1020595525", "1020600160", "...
## $ "Date"       (chr) "09/26/2012 17:01:00", "09/26/2012 17:22:46", "09/26/2012 17:24:22", "0...
## $ "Username"   (chr) "LoudpackMariee", "Sofia_Torrez", "PaterGH13", "WP2_DotCom", "RadicalWi...
## $ "Text"       (chr) "RT @marvelousbby: @LaLaaKors no you just say too much on twitter", "I ...
## $ "Location"   (chr) "Niggas wit coke", "San Diego, California", "Barcelona, Espa\303\261a",...
## $ "Followings" (chr) "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
## $ "Followers"  (chr) "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
```

Comment: Yes and so I want to just try to drop those tweets. Isn't there a way to do that?

Comment: But this solution actually keeps those tweets (i.e. reads in the file perfectly). Do you just not want tweet quotes in your data set?

Comment: Hi. sorry, I did not understand the last code you wrote (starting from, "tmp <- readLines("~/Desktop/tweet.csv", skip=1)"). Do you mean that reads them in perfectly or this one "read.table(text=lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6],header=TRUE,sep=",")"? If you mean this one (read.table(text=lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6],header=TRUE,sep=",")), then what do I do about the error that says line 11 did not have 7 elements? Thanks

Comment: You are confusing two different answers. If you run the code I have above, it reads your tweets file in fine on my system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the rows with more than 7 fields,

```
lines <- readLines('chaotic.txt')
library(stringr)
dat1 <- read.table(text=lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6],header=TRUE,sep=",")
head(dat1,2)
 #   Tweet.ID                Date       Username
 #1 1020580305 09/26/2012 17:01:00 LoudpackMariee
 #2 1020600792 09/26/2012 17:42:49      LexDLutor
                                                                                        #Text
#1                           RT @marvelousbby: @LaLaaKors no you just say too much  on twitter
#2 coke boyz _ instru (prod by Lex Lut'Or) by @LexDLutor via #soundcloud http://t.co/5WW5i1uT
 #           Location Followings Followers
 #1    Niggas wit coke          0         0
 #2 Bruxelles Belgique          0         0
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset `COKE.csv`

```
 lines <- readLines('COKE.csv')
 library(stringi)
 lines1 <- lines[stri_count_fixed(lines, ',')==6]
 dat <- read.table(text= lines1, header=TRUE, sep=",", quote=NULL, comment='')
 dim(dat)
 #[1] 229012      7
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I get the following: dat1 <- read.table(text=lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6],header=TRUE,sep=",")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 111 did not have 7 elements

Comment: using this: dat1 <- read.table(text=lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6],header=TRUE,sep=",", fill=TRUE)  seems to work (no error messages). when I check it with fix(dat1), it is now showing extra variables (up to var17), but ncol(dat1) reports back 7.

Comment: here is a more representative dataset.

Comment: "Tweet ID","Date","Username","Text","Location","Followings","Followers"
"1020608358","09/26/2012 17:46:40","SimplySophie","RT BreezysLullaby: i asked for a coke not strawberry milkshake @mcdonalds!!!! http://t.co/DwC8l6iZ","Liverpool","0","0"
"1020608401","09/26/2012 17:46:41","danielzol4nski","RT @heymarkey: "@wezhopwood: A Cinema was robbed last night of £754, thieves took a bag of malteasers, a pick n mix and a large coke." h ...","Krim+Azealia's block list (UK)","0","0"
"1020644783","09/26/2012 19:00:54","klierley","Cheery coke? LOL http://t.co/bGMg2cAV","the hundred acre woods.","0","0"

Comment: `"Tweet ID","Date","Username","Text","Location","Followings","Followers"
    "1020608358","09/26/2012 17:46:40","Siphie","RT ullaby: i asked for a coke not strawberry milkshake mcdonalds!!!! http://t.co/DwC8l6iZ","Liverpool","0","0"
    "1020608401","09/26/2012 17:46:41","dan4nski","RT @heymarkey: "pwood: A Cinema was robbed last night of £754, thieves took a bag of malteasers, a pick n mix and a large coke." h ...","Krim+Azealia's block list (UK)","0","0"
     "1020644783","09/26/2012 19:00:54","klierlyshirley","Cheery coke? LOL http://t.co/bGMg2cAV","the hundred acre woods.","0","0" `

Comment: did you check fix(dat1) and did it show many new variables at the end?

Comment: I get up to var26. Doesn't that imply it is misreading the data, as having 26+7=33 columns? I see that str(dat1) gives only 7 but why the var26?

Comment: I am not aware of the upload function (or the way to show code) in the comments. Where can I find the upload?

Comment: @onyourmark I meant I posted the screenshot.  If you can share your file in dropbox or something, it would be easier to check.

Comment: Hello. Here is the full file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lzvmioxakrmisw/COKE%20%281%29.7z?dl=0

Comment: there are some lines that we are not able to encode properly and these should be deleted as well if they end up with more than 7 fields. If they have 7 fields they can be let alone. Also, in your opinion, will     lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6]      eliminate all records with more or less than 7 fields?

Comment: won't  lines[str_count(lines, ',')==6] delete those lines?

Comment: @Onyourmark On my post below the `Update`.  BTW, you can use `str_count` from `stringr` as well.  I used `stringi` as it is faster.

Comment: when I load COKE.csv into Excel and count the number of blank cells in column 8 I get 343763 which most probably means that 206 rows have more than 7 fields. If I run the code in the update there there are about 100,000 records that are not included in the result set. Do you know why there is such a big difference? Excel should read extra commas as extra fields but not the way the update does.

Comment: @Onyourmark Not sure why it is that way.  But, as you spotted, there are that many `records having more than 7 fields in the dataset provided.

Comment: you mean because of this in the update right? dim(dat)
 #[1] 229012      7

Comment: @onyourmark  If you want to read all the lines, I guess you can use `fill=TRUE` option.